# MySQL 5.7 | group by | distinct | aggregation error

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct, aggregate-functions, mysql-5.7

I am using MySQL 5.7.

I have a table as following:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id | currentcy_id | rate |      created_at     |
--------------------|------|---------------------|
|  1 |      1       |   1  | 2017-11-07 23:19:48 |
|  2 |      2       |   2  | 2017-11-07 23:20:48 |
|  3 |      3       |   4  | 2017-11-07 23:21:48 |
|  4 |      1       |   2  | 2017-11-07 23:22:48 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to get the latest value of each distinct `currency_id` by doing the following:

```
SELECT `currentcy_id`, `rate`, MAX(`created_at`)  
FROM `currency_reates` 
GROUP BY (`currentcy_id`)
```

I also tried the DISTICT function as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`currentcy_id`), `rate`, MAX(`created_at`)  
FROM `currency_reates`
```

I get an error from both queries regarding aggregation.

**Note:** I disabled the `STRICT` option in MySQL and it works, but I don't want to do it this way, I want the right way (the new one).

Comment: `rate` also needs aggregate function or in `group by`

Comment: @LONG, I need the last `rate` according to `created_at`.

Comment: I see, then you can try:     `SELECT currentcy_id, MAX(rate) FROM currency_reates A GROUP BY (currentcy_id) WHERE created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at ) FROM currency_reates as B WHERE B.currentcy_id = A.currentcy_id)`, this is not the best query to get the result, but might be easier to understand

Comment: `select * from currency_reates where id = (select id from currency_reates order by end_date desc limit 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT C.`currentcy_id`, C.`rate`, C.`created_at`
FROM `currency_reates` C
JOIN ( SELECT `currentcy_id`,  MAX(`created_at`)  as m_date
       FROM `currency_reates` 
       GROUP BY (`currentcy_id`)
     ) as T
  ON C.`currentcy_id` = T.`currentcy_id`
 AND C.`created_at` = T.m_date
```

Comment: Yes this is the most common approach.. The topicstarter only needs to know if there are two or more (max) timestamps that are the same within a group (currentcy_id) this query will return those results to.

Comment: That's it, but it's too much to do compared to old MySQL version. any explanation why they moved to this approach?

Comment: @CairoCoder Because people cared about the integrity of their data.

Comment: @Strawberry What are they talking about here about old and new? this the only way I know beside correlated queries.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza They're a bit confused (or else, I am) but essentially  I think they're just talking about MySQL's decision to have strict mode enabled by default.

Comment: @Strawberry I actually want to know why they decide to user `STRICT` and prevent such queries like old versions.

Comment: @CairoCoder Well the strict is the way every other database do it. You can change the setting if you want  https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-disable-strict-mode-in-mysql-5-7.html

Comment: @CairoCoder Because without STRICT mode enabled, you're liable to return (at best) indeterminate or (at worst) erroneous results. So, for instance, your original query returns an arbitrary (actually indeterminate) rate for each currentcy_id[sic]